# React Native Firebase auth().signInWithPhoneNumber() return unexpected error in Release APK

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have been working on react native app development which I've already built a released version. 
unfortunately, released version has caused me an unexpected error when the app is calling auth().signInWithPhoneNumber() function. In contrary, the debug version does not cause any problem.

As I couldn't get any logs in released app, I've taken a step further to logged down the error message. It turned out that, the return error message from firebase was

> {{'line': 101, 'column': 244, 'sourceURL': 'index.android.bundle'}}

Therefore, I have put some researched on index.android.bundle, it seem that the resources in google were all about JS did not bundle it correctly. In such case, without hesitation I would try any solutions that I could search online.

One of the solution I've followed was
https://medium.com/@shreyasnisal/solved-packing-error-in-react-native-release-apk-f887687edc4f

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

There is no luck on solving this issue as well.

The codes following where the error returns

```
async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: string, event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

      if (confirmation) {
        setConfirm(confirmation);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Check Exist Error2 - ' + err.message);
      console.log('error Code - ' + err.code);
      setErrorOccured(true);
      if (err.code === 'missing-phone-number') {
        console.log('Missing Phone Number.');
        setErrorMsg('Missing Phone Number.');
      } else if (err.code === 'auth/invalid-phone-number') {
        console.log('Invalid Phone Number.');
        setErrorMsg('Invalid Phone Number.');
      } else if (err.code === 'auth/quota-exceeded') {
        console.log('SMS quota exceeded.');
        setErrorMsg('SMS quota exceeded.Please try again later.');
      } else if (err.code === 'auth/user-disabled') {
        console.log('User disabled.');
        setErrorMsg('Phone Number disabled. Please contact support.');
      } else {
        console.log('Unexpected Error.' + err.code);
        axios.post(`https://myapi/error`, err);
        setErrorMsg('Unexpected Error Occured. Please contact support.');
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * */
  project.ext.react = [
    // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",

    // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
    // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
    // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
    entryFile: "index.android.js",

    // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
    bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",

    // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
    bundleInDebug: false,

    // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
    bundleInRelease: true,

    // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
    // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
    // The configuration property can be in the following formats
    //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
    //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
    // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
    // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
    // bundleInBeta: true,

    // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
    // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
    devDisabledInStaging: true,
    // The configuration property can be in the following formats
    //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
    //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'

    // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
    root: "../../",

    // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
    jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",

    // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
    jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",

    // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
    // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
    resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
    // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
    // require('./image.png')), in release mode
    resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",

    // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
    // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
    // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
    // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
    // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
    inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],

    // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
    nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],

    // supply additional arguments to the packager
    extraPackagerArgs: []
  ]

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.testtrace"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }

        release {
            storeFile file('.keystore')
            storePassword '-'
            keyAlias '.keystore'
            keyPassword '-'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

crashlytics {
  enableNdk true
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_crashlytics")
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation project(':lottie-react-native')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me to look at this issue as I wished to launch my app as soon as possible.

Thank you

Comment: I should have thrown the error with error.code & error.message to see the exactly errors in javascaript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the real reason behind the issue, it was due to firebase "auth/app-not-authorized" error, which was not stated in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors.

fortunately, it was solved by adding matched fingerprint (sha1 & sha256) that generated by the released keystore.

Comment: I am also having same issue. I have uploaded sha1 for both debug and release builds. Do I also ned to upload sha256?

Can explain little more, what exactly fixed this for you?

Comment: @shubhamchoudhary normally android will generate sha-1 and sha-256 for your fingerprint. it has to match both to authorize the application.